# Google App Script to add a Smartsheet summary field to a smartsheet and populate it with data from a Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, smartsheet-api

I am trying to add a summary field to a smartsheet using data from a google sheet. I have tried but I cannot get anything to work. I can access both the Google and Smartsheet and am looking for examples of code for GAS to create the field and populate the data.

I tried the Smartsheet documentation and Learning center but I'm lost between the lower level Post commands hey provide and converting that into code using UrlFetchApp